# MySQL Daemon failed to start - RHEL

Tags: mysql, linux, rhel

I had an issue with mysql today where restarting it after an issue with a wordpress plugin caused a too many connections error and hosed mysql.  When I stopped the process that I believed to be causing that issue I now cant seem to get mysql to start.  Below is a copy of mysql.log when trying to start.  Any help would be appreciated.

170720 20:04:33 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
170720 20:04:33 [ERROR] Can't read from messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys'
170720 20:04:33  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 4.0G
170720 20:04:34  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170720 20:04:34  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 3389 2140661223
170720 20:04:34 [ERROR] Aborting

170720 20:04:34  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
170720 20:04:39  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 3389 2140661223
170720 20:04:39 [Note]
170720 20:04:39 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended

Comment: `rpm -qf /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys`

Comment: That outputted MariaDB-server-10.0.31-1.el6.x86_64.  I actually just decided to restore the entire server to a previous backup when it was working.  Appreciate the help though.